# http POST data access

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AnuglarJS and am trying to send a http POST request. The request is sent successfully. However, I cannot access the POST data on the server side. I've tried to modify the headers and request data (per different articles). None seem to work. Here's what I am using,

Client:

```
var user = { name: $scope.username };
$http({
      method: "POST",
      url: "../validation",  
      data: user, 
       }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);           
   });
```

Server:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$name = $request->name;
echo $name;
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: set default content type `$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` or more preferably `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},`

Comment: @Neel That doesn't work.

Comment: have you seen with debugger tool for the request ?also why you are not framing your data like this `data: $.param({
            name: $scope.username           
        }),`

Comment: I am not php user but suspect your angular code what u posted is syntactically wrong because the comma at end of  `data: user,`

Comment: @Neel ok. still doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't work is not helpful.you need to tell us what error exactly you have.create a minimal-verifiable-example and post the actual error.

Comment: There's no error. I still cannot access the POST data at the server-side

Comment: Check your dev tools network tab to see what data is posted.

Comment: @Musa I see the data posted as `{"name":"guest"}`

Comment: I found that there was an error '301 moved permanently'. When I changed the URL to '../validation/index,php' , it worked. Thanks Musa for helping me look into Network. I changed from Chrome to Firefox. No idea why it didnt show up in Chrome.